# Impala AnalysisException: Subqueries are not supported in the HAVING clause

Tags: impala

I have a query where I am selecting destination host names where a user agent string matches and grouping by where there is a distinct srchostname using Impala.

```
select desthostname
from proxy_table 
where useragentstring = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Google Earth Pro/7.3.2.5491 Safari/538.1"
group by desthostname
having count(*) = (select count(distinct srchostname) from proxy_table);
```

But I am running into the error:
`AnalysisException: Subqueries are not supported in the HAVING clause.`

Do you know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this:

```
select desthostname from
(select desthostname,count(*) as cnt
from proxy_table 
where useragentstring = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Google Earth Pro/7.3.2.5491 Safari/538.1"
group by desthostname) A where A.cnt in (select count(distinct srchostname) from proxy_table);
```